python - record and preview webcam at the same time, using e.g. ffmpeg
I want to record webcam with sound using python. After tryng multiple different methods, ffmpeg with the python wrapper showed the best results.
Recording works, but how can I preview the webcam at the same time, so I know where I am pointing the cam at?
I've seen this post, but I dont understand how I could implement this in python, using the wrapper.
Any ideas on how to do this? Or if there is another, easier, solution to record webcam video with sound and preview it simultaneously from within a python (Qt) application?
This is my code so far:
import ffmpeg
import time

process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('video=Integrated Camera:audio=Microphone Array (Realtek(R) Audio)', format='dshow')
    .output('out.mp4', pix_fmt='yuv420p')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stderr=True, quiet=True)
)

# This is just to simulate some time-
time.sleep(10)

process.stdin.write('q'.encode())
process.communicate()
process.wait()

print('done')


It seems more straight forward to do this all within Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-camera-example.html

this seems very straight forward, I tried the camera example with PySide6 but so far I was not able to produce any recording file with it. this seems to be a windows limitation, could this be the case?

Nevermind, this seems to work, the videos where just saved to the default Video Library instead of relative to the python script.
